# how does the server know that the client is still connected?

Tags: c++, client-server, connect

a client establishes a connection to a server process. how does the server knows that the client is still connected?

For example the server is a web server and a client is a browser. Let's assume that the requirement is that the server should always wants to know that the client is connected.

How is that implemented/designed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP Sessions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29) can help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about sockets.

The server will know that the client is still connected because when the client disconnect, the connection will be torn down. The server will be notified of this as part of the normal workings of TCP, and thus the associated socket will be marked as no longer being associated with a connection.

When the server process goes to read or write from this socket, they'll be informed that the connection no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TCP is being used, you will receive a zero byte read on the socket when the other side has disconnected. This signifies that the connection is closed.

If the server is writing data to a socket while the connection is closed, it will also receive notification that the connection has been closed, but exactly how this notification is given is different across implementations.